# Asp.net automatic form processing

Tags: asp.net, email

I often have to code simple contact forms or forms where the data is basically just dumped into an email and sent to someone. Although this doesn't always take very long it can be boring.

Are there any free controls similar to this one [Auto Email](http://www.360impact.com/products/auto_email.aspx). Does anyone have another method they use with success?

Answer (score 0):

As I underestand You have a form which you ( or your user ) completes it and then submit this form to an e-mail Address. And you want to Automate this procedure which whenever the form completes system submit the form ( and this let you complete the form value in code- behind ).

So if this procedure is ture it is too easy to do this.

All you need is a little Ajax in your page. As you are coding in Asp.net you can use Asp.net Ajax and trigg the submit button in code behind like this

UpdatePanel1.Update();

---

If I am wrong please add some more information

Comment: Not really. I want a function that will parse the submitted form and automatically create an email from the form labels and input fields. It should be able to do it for any form with minimal intervention from me.

Comment: @Wiliam -  So I think that you need a function which takes a stream and inside the function you have to split the stream with a seperator and create a mail form. just note that you have to send a templated stream which you ensure that the exact part of splited stream are for the axact part of mail